# Cannot implicitly convert type sting[] to 'system.collections.arraylist'

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

I'm new to asp.net

Here is my code:

```
public static string pathGetFile = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathGetFile"].ToString();

public bool TransferFile(string idcard)
{
    //string file = "";
    try
    {
        Sftp sftp = new Sftp(url, user);                            

        sftp.AddIdentityFile(pathKey);
        sftp.Connect(port);

        string two_char = idcard.Substring(0, 2);

        ArrayList filelist = sftp.GetFileList(pathGetFile);
        bool is_twochar = false;
        string temp = "";
        foreach (var item in filelist)
        {
            temp += item.ToString() + "/n";
            if (item.ToString() == two_char)
            {
                is_twochar = true;
            }
        }
```

the erorr occurs at "`ArrayList filelist = sftp.GetFileList(pathGetFile);`"

and the error is:

> `"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList'"`

Comment: I am guessing `GetFileList()` returns a `string[]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can just change `ArrayList filelist = sftp.GetFileList(pathGetFile);`
to `var filelist = sftp.GetFileList(pathGetFile);`

`sftp.GetFileList(pathGetFile)` must be returning `string[]` and since I see no need for the rest of the code to use ArrayList, you can just change it to `var` or `string[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `ArrayList` there are almost no reason too. As the error is stating

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to System.Collections.ArrayList

Why not just use

```
var filelist = sftp.GetFileList(pathGetFile);
```

This will create `filelist` as a `string[]` as opposed to an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `sftp.GetFileList(pathGetFile);` returns a `string[]`. A simple fix can either be to write `var filelist` or `string[] filelist` instead of `ArrayList`.